# mootools Resizable from left, not right

Tags: javascript, mootools, resizable

The mootools function [makeResizable](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Drag/Drag) allows you to specify a handle, which means I can set a handle to the left of the element I want to resize. But the drag operation only allows to pull from the right to the left, not left to right.

Is there a way I can modify the function to let me do so? I'd like to be able to use a handle on the left and right of my element.

Edit:
Also, I have set a resizable for another element for vertical resizing. And the logic seems to be inversed. I have to scroll up to max the element smaller. Why would this be? Absolute position on the element is set to `bottom:0; left:0;` (inside a relative container)

Comment: random guess: what happens if you set `direction: rtl;` on the element's css?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

good question!
As far as I know handling both left and right is not possible directly using makeResizable. Btw, by trying to make some tricks using makeDraggable, you could set the element-to-be-resized and 2 draggers (1 left, 1 right) and by dragging each element you could set the left/width properties of the element-to-be-resized. i.e.

html:

```
<div id="resizable">
    <div class="fakeHandler" id="leftHandler">
    </div>
    <div class="fakeHandler" id="rightHandler">
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#resizable{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    border:1px solid #787878;
    position:absolute;
    left:100px;
    bottom:100px;
}
.fakeHandler{
    height:100px;
    width:10px;
    position:absolute;
}
#leftHandler{
    left:0;
    cursor:e-resize;
}
#rightHandler{
    right:0;
    cursor:w-resize;
}
```

js: [check this fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/steweb/tHW2K/)

This example is just a *sketch* that has to be improved . However I think it's a good starting point, or an idea ;)

Comment: Works great thanks. Just need to get rid of that little "gitter" when you resize from left

Comment: You're welcome! About that bad behaviour..you'd need to fix the left and width calculation..coz it's something I did quickly without thinking a lot.. btw tomorrow whenever I ll have 5 free mins I ll check and fix it ;)